# Подключение TypeScript файлов в .cshtml вьюхи

Tags: angular2, typescript, asp.net-core

Создал новый проект на базе `angular 2` в `ASP.NET Core`. В `Index.cshtml` подключается целая папка со стандартными файлами `ts` и `js`:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

Могу ли я подключить отдельно нужные мне файлы или компоненты для определенной вьюхи?

Или мне нужно создавать заново все конфигурационные файлы, аналогичным в папке `ClientApp` с компонентами и подключать их, так же как и в примере?